# How to Generate Code 128 and Qr code in Crystal Report?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to Generate Qr code and Code 128 in crystal report. I fetch data using dataset to crystal report but don't know about barcodes in crystal report. I installed zxing in project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a font that will "transform" your string into a barcode. Just use that font on the barcode field.